# scroll method in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

scroll method not working but ı can use style.left and get it done. How can i use the scroll method and get the same result ?

```js
let counter = 0
const prev = document.querySelector('#prev')
const next = document.querySelector('#next')
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider')
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper')
const max = document.querySelectorAll('.slide').length - 1

function sliderFunc() {
  if (counter < max) {
    counter++
    console.log(counter)
    slider.style.left = '-' + 800 * counter + 'px'
    // ` ${-800*counter}px`
  } else {
    counter = 0
    slider.style.left = '-' + 800 * counter + 'px'
  }
}

let timer = setInterval(sliderFunc, 3000)

wrapper.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  clearInterval(timer)
  console.log('üzerinde')
})
wrapper.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  timer = setInterval(sliderFunc, 3000)
  console.log('durdu')
})

next.addEventListener('click', sliderFunc)

prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (counter >= 0) {
    counter--
    console.log(counter)
    slider.style.left = '-' + 800 * counter + 'px'
  }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #333;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#prev,
#next {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 15px);
}

#prev {
  left: 15px;
}

#next {
  right: 15px;
}

.slider {
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
}

.slide {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="prev">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-left"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./img1.jpg)">
        SLIDE 1
      </div>
      <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./img2.jpg)">
        SLIDE 2
      </div>
      <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./img4.jpg)">
        SLIDE 3
      </div>
      <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./img5.jpg)">
        SLIDE 4
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="next">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/66df44010b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

My JavaScript code above is working fine. I attempted to achieve the same result using a different approach, namely the scroll method, but it didn't work, and it also didn't give any error messages.

This is not working... How should I use the scroll method?

```js
let counter = 0
const prev = document.querySelector('#prev')
const next = document.querySelector('#next')
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider')
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper')
const max = document.querySelectorAll('.slide').length - 1
let count = 0

console.log(wrapper.offsetWidth) //800
console.log(slider.offsetWidth)  //3200

function sliderFunc() {
  counter++
  slider.scroll({
    top: 0,
    left: -(wrapper.offsetWidth * counter),
    // left: wrapper.offsetWidth * counter 
    // not working either
    behavior: 'smooth',
  })
}
next.addEventListener('click', sliderFunc)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #333;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#prev,
#next {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 15px);
}

#prev {
  left: 15px;
}

#next {
  right: 15px;
}

.slider {
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
}

.slide {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="prev">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-left"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./img1.jpg)">
        SLIDE 1
      </div>
      <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./img2.jpg)">
        SLIDE 2
      </div>
      <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./img4.jpg)">
        SLIDE 3
      </div>
      <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./img5.jpg)">
        SLIDE 4
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="next">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/66df44010b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I assumed, with my edit, that you didn't change the HTML and CSS code for your second example. Please edit the post if that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have added negative value for 'left' in scroll method. Seems that is preventing it from scrolling. You can add a positive value and then increase or decrease the counter as needed.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

---

Edit: I have updated your code and made some changes on css and js files. Now, scrolling works. You can make changes to previous and next button to achieve full functionality.

Below are the modifications made -

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll; // <----- new
}
```

JS:

```
wrapper.scroll({
    top: 0,
    left: wrapper.offsetWidth * counter, // <----- new
    behavior: 'smooth',
  })
```

Comment: yes I know when the positive doesn't work I tried negative one... still not working

Comment: I have added the code to my answer. Please replace your code with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your CSS code a bit. The main problem lied in having your `.wrapper` hiding overflow elements. I moved `overflow: hidden` to `.slider` instead.

Also, I refactored the sliderFunc() code slightly and moved the `counter` modification bit to a new method, in preparation for when you want to implement the left scrolling, which will use the new `numberOfSlides` variable and an if statement.

Other than that, I used the modulus operator (%) to make the slider loop around without having to use an if statement.

```js
let counter = 0
const prev = document.querySelector('#prev')
const next = document.querySelector('#next')
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider')
const slideWidth = document.querySelector('.slide').offsetWidth;
const numberOfSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide').length;

function sliderFunc() {
  const newPosition = slideWidth * (counter % numberOfSlides);

  slider.scroll({left: newPosition, top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
}

function scrollRight() {
  counter++;
  sliderFunc();
}

next.addEventListener('click', scrollRight)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #333;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#prev,
#next {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
}

#prev {
  left: 15px;
}

#next {
  right: 15px;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  min-width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="prev">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-left"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./img1.jpg)">
        SLIDE 1
      </div>
      <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./img2.jpg)">
        SLIDE 2
      </div>
      <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./img4.jpg)">
        SLIDE 3
      </div>
      <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./img5.jpg)">
        SLIDE 4
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="next">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/66df44010b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```